# how to find where the file is used. example textures, 3d models, materials

Tags: c#, file, unity-game-engine

I have a lot of extra files in my project how to find out which is used and which is not. for example textures, 3d models, materials

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

[Editor Log:](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ReducingFilesize.html)

> This information is available in the **Editor Log** just after you
> have performed the build. Go to the Console window (menu: **Window** >
> **General** > **Console** ), click the small drop-down panel in the top right, and select **Open Editor Log**.

[image]